# Printing input colored to window

Tags: java, javafx

im trying to create a window with javafx and print my incomming input into this window in differend colors.

Here is what i try to do in JavaFx to add a line after the window is there.

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Java chat client"); 
    tf = new TextFlow();
    Text t;
    t=new Text("tetd\n");
    t.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    tf.getChildren().addAll(t);
    t=new Text("blblblb");
    tf.getChildren().add(t);
    group = new Group(tf);
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 650, 150, Color.WHITE);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show(); 
}
```

and this is what i try to do in my main to add new text:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(Client.class);
    Text t;
    t=new Text("tetd\n");
    t.setFill(Color.RED);
    tf.getChildren().add(t);
    group.getChildren().add(tf);
}
```

when i try this i get an

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = Group@1706bae[styleClass=root]

any advice how i can add the text?

Thanks for help

Comment: It is possible the same way it was in Swing: using an HTML-capable component. In FX this is called `WebView`

Comment: You can either HTML-format the text and use a `WebView`, as @TimothyTruckle suggests, or use a [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) and place `Text` elements in it. Each `Text` can have a different `fill` set on it, to change the color.

Comment: How do i updade the scene to add the new incomming line? @James_D

Comment: With a web view it would be tricky; probably you would just have to recreate the whole thing and reload it. With a `TextFlow` just add the new `Text` object in the usual way. You need to actually try it and ask specific questions if you get stuck - right now this question is on the borderline of being off-topic for this forum.

Comment: Why do you mention a swing GUI if you're asking about JavaFX? This makes even less sense, since the swing GUI also doesn't seem to be working as desired.

Comment: Why do you have code in the `main()` method after the call to `launch()`???

Answer (score -1):

A great way of going about this and also a great learning opportunity is to use CSS for this. The below code is an example that will change the text color of a TextArea.

```
.text-area{
    -fx-text-fill: green;
}
```

Then you could add this style sheet to your node (In this case the text area) like so.

```
@FXML TextArea myTextArea;

@Override
public void initialize(){
    myTextArea.getStyleSheets.add("Path to your style sheet (i.e bin/textColor.css"));
}
```

If you are already familiar with javaFX and the initializable interface this will make perfect sense to you. In any other case I strongly suggest that you do learn about these features. As far as just a line you could just enable the underline and set the text to a bunch of white space. Hope this helps.

Comment: But so i only have green text can i add somehow multiple colores to the textarea?

Comment: In javaFX yes it is possible.

Comment: How? Via css or what classes do i need to use? And can you give mir an smale exaple? Thank you.

Comment: Simply use a TextFlow objects and before you add your Text objects set their style to your desired color (i.e Text t1 = new Text();
t1.setStyle("-fx-text-color: blue); ) Then all you have to do is add this to your TextFlow object. You can do this with as many objects as you want. If you wanted to each line could have a specific font color, size, etc and you could store these settings in a CSS file and add them individually to each object.

Comment: You cannot apply multiple styles to different text within a `TextArea`.

Comment: But you can with a TextFlow

Comment: What does a `TextFlow` have to do with your answer?

Comment: Just a CSS example